# Prevent XSS attacks on user uploaded Javascript and HTML files

Tags: javascript, html, security, xss

On our website, we would like to allow users to upload / edit **HTML** and especially **Javascript** files.

We understand that this operation might be a security hazard and would like to take some measures to ensure no dangerous code is inserted...

We would like to have a list of Regex expressions to filter out unwanted expressions from the user input files/script.

For example:

1. Filter outgoing links to resources/scripts (link rel, script src etc..)
2. Filter the window.parent objects from within scripts
3. Filter out HTML Attributes which execute code on the window.parent
4. Prevent access to the cookie / other sensitive user data
5. Prevent posting data to remote servers (XMLHttpRequest / ajax / etc...)
6. What else?

Please note that **all user content scripts will be executed within an iframe**.  so an answer which can address all `window.parent` cases might be useful.

Is this completely wrong practice?

Comment: Filtering by a regex is wrong, given the existence of [obfuscators](http://www.jsfuck.com)

Comment: The answer questions of this type is always the same. Use. a. parser. HTML parsers that allow you to sanitize the incoming HTML. JS parsers allow you to sanitize the incoming JS. Trying to do this with regex is a waste of time, it can never work, for the simple reason that regex is technically incapable of parsing higher-level languages. Invest your time into the proper tool from the beginning.

Comment: Also, don't do validation on the client side. The server does input validation. Anything you do on the client side is fluff that you can add for convenience and for nothing else.

Comment: @Tomalak do you know a good parser for that matter?

Comment: Depends on your server side, doesn't it?

Comment: @Tomalak .net c#

Comment: There are a few options available for parsing HTML, the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/) being a popular one, another one I found is [AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp). For JS a few projects exist as well, you could use the parser part of [jint](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint) and I've found some others, too. Look around for yourself. The procedure is the same for JS and HTML. Let the parser analyze the source code, inspect the tree you get from the parser, white-list what you want to keep, throw out everything else (or reject the input entirely).

Comment: Encoding the user input is also a good idea. Starting from .NET 4.5, you have the [AntiXssEncoder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.web.security.antixss.antixssencoder(v=vs.110).aspx) namespace available, which offers functions to sanitize user input depending on the context: `HtmlEncode`, `CssEncode`, `HtmlAttributeEncode`, `UrlEncode`... If your version is less than 4.5, you have the [AntiXssLibrary](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AntiXSS/).